# Decode string to valid JSON in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am rendering string javascript variable init statements at server side (using ASP MVC, but I do not think it matters) The string variable content is a valid JSON at server side, and encoded when rendered to html. My rendered statement looks like this:

```
 var myvariable = '{&quot;prefix&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Grid&...
```

Quatation marks and other special chars in the string were encoded to html entities, which is completely OK, unless this encoding the variable declaration would by syntactically incorrect.

However I must get back the original string content at client side which was a correct JSON at server side. How can I accomplish this with javascript or jQuery? (Please note, then I do know how to get a javascript object from JSON, I am not asking for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about?

```
var myjsonobject = JSON.parse(decodeHtml(myvariable));
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
   return txt.value;
}
```

Note that it's not tested

EDIT: Tested it
https://jsfiddle.net/Lmz20s5z/

EDIT2: *See the console log for results

Answer (score 0):

On server side you can escape quotation marks with a backspace \"  then you can just do JSON.parse(string) on that string clientside.

```
JSON.parse('{\"prefix\":\"\",\"name\":\"Grid\"}');
```

Comment: Not only quotation marks are there, but script parts also. I do not want to reinvent the wheel, ASP MVC have server side infrastructure to render a correct html string by escaping all specials with html entities. Now I am looking for the inverse transformation in javascript or jQuery